# CDI Eager Application scoped bean

Tags: cdi, jsf-2.2

Since `@ManagedBean(eager = true)` will be deprecated, How do you create a **eager application scoped cdi bean**?

Answer (score 4):

Solved this by making use of CDI extension framework:

1. Create Qualifier:

   ```java
   @Qualifier
   @Target(value = {ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER,     ElementType.TYPE})
   @Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
   public @interface Eager {
   }
   ```
2. Create Extension implementation with observer method:

   ```java
   public class EagerCDIExtension implements Extension {

           public void afterDeploymentValidation(@Observes AfterDeploymentValidation event, BeanManager beanManager) {
           beanManager.getBeans(Object.class, new AnnotationLiteral<Eager>() {
           }).parallelStream().filter(bean -> bean.getBeanClass().isAnnotationPresent(ApplicationScoped.class)).forEach(bean -> {
               beanManager.getReference(bean, bean.getBeanClass(), beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean)).toString();
           });
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create: `META-INF/services/javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Extension`
4. Register extension implementatoin class in above file i.e:

   ```
   pypackage.EagerCDIExtension
   ```

Comment: With this way I need to mark any injection as `@Any` or `@Eager`. Is it true?

Comment: No, the bean itself if I am right, so only one place